# Can't setup apm-integration-testing for debugging kibana

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elastic-apm

I'm following the kibana developer's guide, and I want to debug the application using APM.
so I'm following this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/kibana-debugging.html .

first I clone the apm-integration-testing repo, then I run `./scripts/compose.py start master --no-kibana`

however after running the above code, I get this error:`Please start Docker before running the apm-integration-testing.`

I understand that running apm requires docker and docker-compose, but there is no clear documentation on how to get it all to run.

If someone has setup apm-integration-testing successfully I can use some help.

Edit:
Here is the compose.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""CLI for starting a testing environment using docker-compose."""
from __future__ import print_function

import logging
import os
import subprocess
import sys

from modules.cli import LocalSetup


def main():
    # Enable logging
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    setup = LocalSetup(sys.argv[1:])
    setup()


def verify_if_docker_is_installed():
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(
            'docker ps', stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'), shell=True).decode('utf8').strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("Please start Docker before running the apm-integration-testing.")
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    verify_if_docker_is_installed()
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the docker service before executing the script
`systemctl start docker`

Comment: I ran the command, but still the same problem

Comment: I edited the question and added the compose.py file that prints the error

Comment: Is the user that you are running as part of the ```docker``` group? If not, add the user and test.

Comment: thanks, adding the user to the group worked for me